# Weird results when trying to calculate linear regression and display it in matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create scatter plot for my data and to calculate and dusplay the linear regression and the correlation on top of my chart.

My original scatter plot looks like this:
[image]

But when I try to calculte the regression line  and display it I get something very weird:

[image]

This is how I calculated and display it:

```
#I created one database from two different databases
merged_data=pd.merge(byDH.to_frame(),NITbyDH,how='inner',on='plant')
merged_data.head(18)

#I have calculte the fit
fit = np.polyfit(merged_data.NDVI,merged_data.nitrogen,1)
print(fit)

#made X and Y axis into values in order to catcch only the relevant data
x=merged_data['NDVI'].values
y=merged_data['nitrogen'].values

# Create Figure (empty canvas)
fig = plt.figure()

# Add set of axes to figure
axes = fig.add_axes([1, 1, 1, 1]) # left, bottom, width, height (range 0 to 1)



# Regression lines.

plt.plot(merged_data.NDVI,fit[0]*merged_data.NDVI+fit[1], color='darkblue', linewidth=2)


# Regression equations.
plt.text(2,2,'y={:.2f}+{:.2f}*x'.format(fit[1],fit[0]),color='darkblue',size=12)


#plot

plt.scatter(y,x,alpha=0.5)
plt.title('NDVI vs Nitrogen 17/6/2019')
plt.xlabel('NDVI')
plt.ylabel('Nitrogen')
plt.show()
```

*If you have any more tips -things I could do better beside the chart, feel free to tell, i'm a beginner and I seek to learn more

## I have used ti slink to create the regression:

https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-with-python-c9ab422ec29c

edit: after fixing x and y, I get tiny chart
[image]

Comment: You should provide a minimum, reproducible example. Otherwise, you have switched your `x` and `y` axes.  NDVI has values between -1 and 1. In scatter, you switch them (`plt.scatter(y,x,alpha=0.5)`), you should have them in the same order when you fit.

Comment: It worked, but now the size decreased a lot. I have tried in fig to add the size (fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) but still tiny. why would it happen?

Comment: What do you mean, that the size is very small? You mean when the regression line? The axes are switched there too. `merged_data.NDVI` is your `y`, not your `x`.

Comment: I mean that now after fixing it and replacing the x and the y as you suggested, the size of the chart is small so I can't see it

Comment: Try this: `x=merged_data['NDVI'].values
y=merged_data['nitrogen'].values`. `fit = np.polyfit(x,y,1)` `plt.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.5)` `plt.plot(x,fit[0]*x+fit[1], color='darkblue', linewidth=2)
`

Comment: still tiny, what do you think makes it happen?

Comment: I jave just figured out the the linear euqation appears on the other edge of the box and maybe that's why it's so small

Comment: Yes, you position it at (2,2). Try positioning it at (0.78,3)